# Javascript - Jquery - click(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this javascript ?

```
      $("#parent-project").attr("data-id").click(function(){ 
       //some code...
      }
```

The console output is:

> Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: Sure, `.attr("data-id")` returns a string, which has no `click` method

Comment: how can I solve this issue ? Because the only way to select the right div is by data-id attribute

Comment: @NathanSchwarz, in my answer an element with id parent-project and **attribute** `data-id` is selected

Comment: `$("#parent-project[data-id="+myVar+"]").click(function(){ // code }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return a string value to which a click handler cannot be attached. I imagine you wanted

```
$("#parent-project[data-id]").click(function(){ 
       //some code...
      }
```

In which `[]` is notation for attribute

Comment: I've got an other question. Is it possible to compare only the data-id of different elements ?

Comment: @NathanSchwarz, what do mean compare? Can you give me some HTML and what you want so I can better understand?

Comment: I would like to compare the data-id to get something like :`if ($("#parent-project[data-id]") != ("#open_project[data-id]")) {`  but only compare the data-id

Comment: @NathanSchwarz, like this `if ($("#parent-project").attr("data-id") != $("#open_project").attr("[data-id]"))`

Comment: @NathanSchwarz, there was typo in the comment above, I fixed it